# Convenience functions for specific responsive ranges in LESS

Tags: less, responsive-design

I really want to quit typing:

```
@media (min-width: @min-tablet-width) and (max-width: @max-tablet-width) {
  // styles for tablets
}
```

all over my LESS files.

As far as I know, there's no way in LESS to move this into a function, like:

```
.tablet() {
  // styles for tablets
}
```

Are there other solutions?

Comment: I wish LESS would allow you to nest media types inside the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this : https://github.com/dalou/bootstrap3-less-mixins
ex :

```
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    .phone-only({
         font-size: 14px;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer at this point in time is: **no**.

EDIT: see Dalou's answer above.